# PHP DOM Parser Moving Closing Div Tag

Tags: php, html, string, domparser

here's my code:

```
$myHtml = '
<div class="div-class">
    <p>text</p>

    <p><a href="#">text</a></p>
</div>

<ul class="some-class">
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="something something"><img src="" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank" title=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank" title=""><img src=""></a>
    </li>
</ul>
';

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($myHtml, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
$anchors = $xpath->query("//a[@title='something something']");
$list = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='some-class']")[0];
foreach ($anchors as $a) {
    $list->removeChild($a->parentNode);
}

var_dump($doc->saveHTML());
```

Essentially, I am trying to remove a list item that contains an anchor tag with a title of 'something something'. However, when I save the html after applying the changes, the list moves inside the div tag. Why would that occur? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`loadHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) tries to correct syntaxis, and it doesn't like the `ul` element being parentless, so it moves it inside the `div`. If you wrap it all around a `body` tag, it'll work correctly.

`loadHTML()` actually automatically should do the wrapping for you were it necessary, but you set the [`LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED`](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) flag, which disables this.

```
<?php
$myHtml = '
<html>
<body>
<div class="div-class">
    <p>text</p>

    <p><a href="#">text</a></p>
</div>

<ul class="some-class">
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="something something"><img src="" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank" title=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank" title=""><img src=""></a>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
';

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($myHtml, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
$anchors = $xpath->query("//a[@title='something something']");
$list = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='some-class']")[0];
foreach ($anchors as $a) {
    $list->removeChild($a->parentNode);
}

var_dump($doc->saveHTML());
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/sWrUO)

Or, without the `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` flag:

```
<?php
$myHtml = '
<div class="div-class">
    <p>text</p>

    <p><a href="#">text</a></p>
</div>

<ul class="some-class">
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="something something"><img src="" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank" title=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank" title=""><img src=""></a>
    </li>
</ul>
';

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($myHtml, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
var_dump (libxml_get_errors());
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
$anchors = $xpath->query("//a[@title='something something']");
$list = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='some-class']")[0];
foreach ($anchors as $a) {
    $list->removeChild($a->parentNode);
}

var_dump($doc->saveHTML());
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/cGN4n)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @ishegg. Is there any other way to do it aside from adding/stripping body tags?

Comment: Did you see the edited answer? If you remove the `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` it will work without changing anything else.

Comment: But if you remove LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED, it would add the body and html tags opening/closing tags.

Comment: I see what you mean. AFAIK, no, `DOMDocument` will always try to “fix” your markup. Maybe as a workaround, wrap everything inside a fake tag and then remove it?

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just using dummy divs and just left them there.